# Efficient reg ex to remove stop words in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7, stop-words

I am using the following reg-ex to remove stop words from a text

```
  pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english')) + r')\b\s*')
```

but it is stripping off the spaces too.As a result of which I am getting back a sentence with no spaces between the remaining words after the removal of stop words. How can I overcome it?

Comment: Any chance one of the strings returned by `stopwords.words('english')` is an empty string?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a derived `stopwords` list.  Either this list contains a space or something or there is some other problem with your code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are getting at, but removing the \s* at the end will stop matching spaces.  Your \b will still look for word boundaries, so maybe that is all you need?

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english')) + r')\b')
```

...but then you will have sentences with two or more spaces together.  Maybe you want:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english')) + r')\b\s?')
```

Also, heed the warnings of the other commenters: if there is an empty or whitespace string in your stopwords list, it might get you in trouble.